# how to restrict specific email domain(s) while submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to restrict submitting a form for specific email domains under html/php. Basically i do not want any user to sign up over specific email domains.

For instance, all email domains will be ok except below ones;

```
@deny.com
@reject.net 
@spam.org
```

How can i achieve this behavior with using jQuery, regular expression or any better way to do so ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Comment: yep, that's why i am here. I am wondering the best way

Comment: you can prefer this http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/email-validation-using-jquery/  and http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/javascript/UNDS040712-JavaScript-Email-Address-validation-using-Regular-Expression.html

Comment: Then show us what you have tried.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Thanks man those scripts work well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Javascript/Jquery to achieve this. Make a function to validate the email

```
var rejectList = [ "deny.com" , "reject.net" ];

function validateEmailField()
{
var emailValue = $('#email-input').val(); // To Get Value (can use getElementById)
var splitArray = emailValue.split('@'); // To Get Array

if(rejectList.indexOf(splitArray[1]) >= 0)
{
// Means it has the rejected domains
return false;
}
return true;

}
```

So just before posting the form execute this function and check the value.

Comment: nice solution. I translated this to php to validate my email address before post. works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same via HTML5 input tag attribute (pattern).
Say for example your domain is foo.com, then the code will be:

```
<input id="email" type="email" pattern="[a-z.]*[@]\bfoo.com" required>
```

Also you can change the error message by using the setCustomValidity of the DOM element.

```
document.getElementById('email').setCustomValidity("Please use an @foo.com email address.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the validation on serverside you can use this script or else you can do the same kind of validation using jquery or javascript

```
    $denied = array("deny.com","reject.net","spam.org");

    function getDomainFromEmail($email)
    {
    // Get the data after the @ 
    $domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);

    return $domain;
    }

    $email = 'the_username_here@deny.com';
    $domain = getDomainFromEmail($email);
    echo $domain;
    if (in_array($domain, $denied)) {
        //denied user alert
        echo "denied";
    }
    else
    {
    //valid user
    echo "valid";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *pattern* attribute in the input tag. it  specifies a regular expression that the  element's value is checked against on form submission.

```
<input type="email" id="email"
   pattern=".+@gmail.com" size="30" required>
```

The code above will only accept emails that end with the domain *@gmail.com*