# Javascript: Form submits after first validation and after applying styles

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, email

Am trying to prevent certain user ids from emails to submit form, like a blacklist, for example denieduser1@domain.com and take denieduser1 and when the user submits the form then appears a bootstrap alert saying something is wrong, the problem is that if you click on the button again the form is submitted without doing validation again, if I remove the part where styles are applied and use an alert then it works so here is the code am using:

For the form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form" onsubmit="return validate()" action="m41lS3nd.php">
```

The validation code:

```
    function validate(){
    e.preventDefault;
var rejectList = [ "denied1" , "denied2" ]; //List of Blacklisted emails or domains
var emailValue = $('#email').val(); // To Get Value (can use getElementById)
var splitArray = emailValue.split('@'); // To Get Array

if(rejectList.indexOf(splitArray[0]) >= 0) //Check if contains any unwanted emails
{
// Means it has the rejected domains
document.getElementById("notification").style.display = "block"; //If unwanted emails are detected will show an alert
document.getElementById("notification").style.marginTop = "5px";
return false;

}else
var contactform = document.getElementById("contact"); //If good email is entered then get the form name and submits the form
contactform.submit();
return true;
}
```

The bootstrap alert:

```
<!--Notification for invalid emails such as spam or unsolicited emails-->          
  <div id="notification" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Oops!</strong>There is something wrong with your email, your reference code is: BL1SE.
  </div>
```

The Submit Button:

```
<button class="btn btn btn-md" type="submit">Send Message &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-1x" style="color: white;"></i></button>
```

I took the code and adapted from this post but cannot comment or contact author and don't know what am doing wrong: [Code for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738960/how-to-restrict-specific-email-domains-while-submit-a-form)

Comment: I tried doing so but then it skips validation and submit the form directly without doing validation I added e.preventDefault; like this: `function validate(){
 e.preventDefault;
var rejectList = [ "denied1" , "denied2" ]; ...}`

Comment: Please never rely on client-side validation alone. (i.e. javascript..). http form submissions can be faked and will bypass any js validation you do. it's good for UX, but that's it.

Comment: In the case when validation is good, it is enough to just return `true`, cause that will trigger the form submit, otherwise you are doing it sort of twice. And yes, remove the `e.preventDefault()` & add the right `else` brace.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Javascript syntax is incorrect because `e.preventDefault();` is referring to a nonexistent variable.  I suspect your Javascript console is reporting the error.

I would also strongly recommend adding `{}` as appropriate after the `else`.  I'd guess that's not going to behave exactly the way you think.  Formatted to show the difference:

```
  } else
    var contactform = document.getElementById("contact"); 
  contactform.submit();
  return true;
```

compared with:

```
  } else {
    var contactform = document.getElementById("contact"); 
    contactform.submit();
  }
  return true;
```

If you added another `else/if` condition that does not return then you will hit `contactform.submit();` without having declaring and initializing `contactform`.